# Does regular intake of (packaged) butter increase the risk of cancer?

Tags: nutrition, cancer, dairy, risks, preservitives

I've heard some rumours from my peers that eating packaged butter on a daily basis could increase the risk of cancer.

This goes from the *presumption* that packaged dairy products contain a certain amount of preservatives which, when ingested, might cause cancer.

Is this really/possibly true? Are there any studies about this that prove/disprove/discusses this matter?

Comment: Can anyone who at least knows of someone with a history of daily butter intake comment about this?

Comment: At least read the packaging to see if your butter contains preservatives or not. Then you can search for more information on **those preservatives** rather than on the very vague (and different from country to country) "packaged butter".